# How to catch Exception thrown by a module in Magento oder save before event

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a magento installation. And we keep getting an exception which is randomly thrown when an order is about placed. We have looked at all logs but cannot find anything, meaning the exception was not logged.

What happens is that, a user will add items to his/her cart, then goes to the checkout and fill in their information. When they click on submit order, they will receive an error message. Meaning the order failed to go through. But the unfortunate the user receives an email confirmation of their order. So some users click again to submit the order again and still get an error message and confirmation email.

What is happening is when the **submit order** button is clicked magento starts the process of saving the order and emits the **sales_order_save_before** of which one modules then fails and throws an exception. Since the exception is not is not caught, its stops the order from getting saved.

So I wanted to know is there a way to handle exceptions thrown by any module that listens to the **sales_order_save_before** event so that I can write the error to the log file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you got an error while you try to checkout, you actually have errors in your log files.

If you can't find any errors in the log files, search for plugins, observers and preferences involved in the checkout, coded in third partis modules, that have this interface as dependecy:

> \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface

Comment: Thanks.. Will try it and get back here. But this seems to be an extreme solution. Because I will now need to look at all the third party code which make use of this Interface